# How to validate in Rails 5 different ActiveRecord for the same action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, api-design

I'm building an authentication system in Rails5 and I have a User for which I want to check the uniqueness and correct format for the email field. I've seen that both errors throw the same exception, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid and I'd like to know how could I manage both cases in a good and elegant way.

This would be the important part of my model User:

```
validates_format_of :email, with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
validates_presence_of :email
validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

And this would be the controller:

```
begin
  user.save!
  render status: :created, json: { msg: 'User was created.' }
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => err
  render status: conflict, json: { msg: err }
end
```

What I'd like to do is to differentiate between Uniqueness error (to return a 409) and format error (to return a 400).

I'll appreciate any comment or help about how to do this check in the better way.

Comment: In this case it would probably make the most sense to validate the input first, and only if it's valid initialize and validate the user object. A common way to do this is via form objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catching the `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception is not the best way to handle this case. Instead, I would suggest to run validation explicitly and checking the `errors` object.

Check Rails API documentation for `ActiveModel::Validations`(https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-errors) and `ActiveModel::Errors` (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html).

After running `user.valid?`, you can investigate `user.errors` object to detect exact kind of validation error. Then you can reply with different response codes as you want:

```
if !user.valid?
  if user.errors[:email] == [" ... uniqueness error ..."]
    # return 409
  elsif user.errors[:email] == [" ... format error ..."]
    # return 400
  else
    # ...
  end
else
  user.save!
  # ...
end
```

Comment: this will check for validation twice - first one you did `valid?` and when you call `save!`. General approach of doing this is handling success case first (with `save` rather than `save!`) and then handling the errors. Also, checking the error with string matching has many gotchas - for example, it won't work with multiple translations (refer I18n); error should be checked against the type rather than the message body.

Comment: @kiddorails Both of your claims are correct. My code should not be the final solution (that' why I inserted so many "..." ;-)) The whole point was to demonstrate that `user.errors` could be used to detect which of the validations is failing.

Comment: @kiddorails could go with `user.save(validate: false)` since it has already been determined to be valid. That being said for this specific case I would check for this specific error independently (since it has a unique workflow). Something like `user.email_unique?` where such a method would return a boolean as well as append the appropriate errors. Right now validation failure has multiple paths and message (or key translation) does not lend to the readability of controller code IMO, as I would have to read further to determine exactly what is being cordoned off.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing `user.save!`, handle `user.save`

```
if user.save
  render status: :created, json: { msg: 'User was created.' }
else
  render status: conflict, json: { msg: user.errors.full_messages.join(', ') }
end
```

the bang version (`save!`) raises the exception if the object is not saved for whatever reason, while the non-bang version (`save`) returns `true` if object is saved and `false`, if it's not.

To further distinguish between type of validation fail, you can use [`#added?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-added-3F):

`user.errors.added? :email, :taken` => true if email uniqueness error

`user.errors.added? :email, :invalid` => true if email formatting error.